# Does SO use `highlight` or `highlightAuto`?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

When reporting a syntax highlighting problem to [`highlight.js`](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js), one of the questions is:

> **Are you using `highlight` or `highlightAuto`?**

What's the answer for SO?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It uses both. Or rather, it is using [`highlightElement()`](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=Highlightauto#highlightelement), plus a plug-in to switch to `highlightAuto()` when no language tag is present.

See the [`full.en.js` source file](https://dev.sstatic.net/js/full.en.js), which contains:

```js
// highlightjs.initHighlighting highlights all `pre code`s by default and requires the lang class to be on the `code` block.
// We only want to highlight our `pre.s-code-block`s specifically and our lang class is on the `pre` block.
// Highlight each of these manually while skipping already highlighted blocks with the added hljs class
$("pre.s-code-block code:not(.hljs)").each(function () {
    StackExchange.highlightjs.instance.highlightElement(this);
});
```

See the section at the end of [`highlightjs-loader.en.js`](https://dev.sstatic.net/js/highlightjs-loader.en.js) to see how the library is configured, including the switch to `highlightAuto()`:

```js
instance.addPlugin({
    "before:highlight": function (data) {
        if (data.language === "no-highlight") {
            data.result = instance.highlightAuto(data.code);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

*Disclaimer: [Current maintainer of Highlight.js here]*

When reporting grammar issues/bugs on GitHub we need to know...

Is the issue a grammar issue:

> You've asked us to highlight JavaScript, but our Javascript highlighting engine simply has a bug.

Or an auto-detection issue:

> Stack Exchange asks us to guess what kind of code it is and we get it wrong. Perhaps we guessed Swift when it's really JavaScript.

In both cases you get poor results, but these are very different issues and we can't help unless we known WHICH is the actual problem.  **This is why we ask `highlight` (grammar issue) or `highlightAuto` (auto detect issue).**

With Stack Exchange it can be hard to tell if you aren't super familiar with how Stack Exchange does highlighting. The best thing is probably to ask on Stack Exchange first, let one of the more experienced members help you decide if it's an auto-detection issue or an actual grammar issue...

Then once that's sorted out you can file a bug on GitHub and let us know the details.

Comment: *"The best thing is probably to ask on Stack Exchange first..."* Right. That's what I did, by posting a question on MSO.

Comment: Awesome.  I was just trying to clarify why we care about this so much. :)

Comment: AFAIK, users can figure this out using the tags that are attached to the question.